# java 8 sum all values of two int arrays with each other

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
int[] ar1 = {1,2,3};
int[] ar2 = {1,2,3};
```

Output:

```
{2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6}
```

I tried something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0,ar1.length).map(x -> IntStream.range(0,ar2.length).map(y -> ar1[y]+ar2[x]));
```

but this does not work:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `IntStream` to `int`.

How can I sum every value of `ar1` with every value of `ar2` in Java 8 using streams?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `flatMap`, since `map` of `IntStream` is expected to map each `int` element of the original `IntStream` to an `int`, not to an `IntStream`.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString (
    IntStream.range(0,ar1.length)
             .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0,ar2.length).map(y -> ar1[x]+ar2[y]))
             .toArray ()));
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

As an alternative to creating an `IntStream` of the indices of the array, you can create an `IntStream` of the elements of the array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString (
    Arrays.stream(ar1)
          .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(ar2).map(y -> x + y))
          .toArray ()));
```

Comment: didn't get why you had created a stream of indexes instead of a stream of their values

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i was testing out some stuff with .range() :)

Comment: @DaftLeech, It is not a good case to test the `range` here :)

Comment: Why exactly are streams like this preferred to, say, a double nested for loop? I understand that they're powerful tools but I don't see their usefulness. I trust the many experienced people who use them but I fail to grasp it personally.

Comment: @corsiKa If you have a lot of data, streams can be split over multiple cores/threaded by the runtime, decreasing execution time. With small datasets as these they cause overhead compared to double nested loops as their setup time is larger, but in large sets, these are useful.

Comment: wouldn't work if the arrays are not of the same size. Although, OP didn't say what he expects in that case

Comment: @corsiKa Tschallacka is missing the point claiming it's about performance. That is a benefit, but it's also about declarative (as opposed to imperative) semantics: instead of saying "iterate over every x and every y and put the sum into an array", you're saying "concatenate every (flatMap aka bind) x summed with every (map) y". If that sort of idea sounds interesting to you, Haskell is the place to learn more. There, you could solve this problem with "liftM2 (+)".

Answer (score 8):

For each `i`th element, you can create a `IntStream` of sums `i + j` of this element and a `j`th element of another array:

```
IntStream.of(ar1).flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(ar2).map(j -> i + j)).toArray();
```

I would not recommend using streams of indexes (`IntStream.range(0,ar1.length)`) where they can be replaced with streams of values themselves (`IntStream.of(ar1)`).

Answer (score 7):

Beside that of the [IntStream#flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.IntFunction-), you can use the [Arrays#stream(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) to create an `IntStream`. for example:

```
int[] sum = Arrays.stream(ar1)
                  .flatMap(left -> Arrays.stream(ar2).map(right -> left + right))
                  .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
//                        ^--- [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```